Lemma 9.11 Montgomery/Vaughan's Multiplicative NT
In the last step of the proof of Lemma 9.11 in the book Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan I couldn't understand the two equalities of the following equation. $$\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le q_1q_2 \\ (kr+b,q_1)=1}}
1 = q_2\phi(q_1) = \frac{\phi(q)}{\phi(r)} \quad (*).$$
Writing integers from 1 to $q_1q_2$ in a matrix form the first equality suggests that $(kr+b,q_1)=1$ iff $(k,q_1)=1$ for $1 \le k \le q_1$ but I couldn't prove this neither.
Writing $q=q_1q_2 r$ , and using equations hold for $\phi$ of products also doesn't lead to the very most RHS.
In this Lemma, $(b,r)=1$ and $r|q$ and if we write $q/r = q_1q_2$ then $q_1$ is the largest divisor of $q/r$ that is relatively prime to $r$.
My question is how $(*)$ holds (both equalities)?

First equality:
Since $(kr + b, q_1) = 1$, there are $\varphi(q_1)$ possibilities ($c_1, \cdots, c_{\varphi(q_1)}$ for $kr + b \mod q_1$. Since $(r, q_1) = 1$, for each possibility $kr + b \equiv c_i \mod q_1$, we can solve for $k$:
$$k \equiv r^{-1} (c_i - b) \mod q_1$$
and so there are $\varphi(q_1)$ possibilities mod $q_1$ as well. For each $r^{-1} (c_i - b) \mod q_1$, there are $q_2$ possible $k$'s such that $1 \leq k \leq q_1q_2$ satisfying $k \equiv r^{-1} (c_i - b) \mod q_1.$ So there are $q_2 \varphi(q_1)$ possibilities in total.
Second equality:
Note that $q_2$ has only prime factors that divide $r$, so $(q_1, q_2r) = 1$, thus $\varphi(q) = \varphi(q_1)\varphi(q_2r)$. It hence suffices to show that
$$\varphi(q_2 r) = q_2 \varphi(r),$$
which would follow from the claim below.
Claim If $q_2 | r^{\infty}$, then $\varphi(q_2 r) = q_2 \varphi(r).$
Proof Since $\varphi$ is multiplicative, one can assume $q_2, r$ are both powers of a fixed prime $p$. Hence let $r = p^e$, $q_2 = p^f$. Then
$$\varphi(q_2r) = \varphi(p^{e+f}) = p^{e+f-1}(p-1)$$
and
$$q_2 \varphi(r) = p^f \varphi(p^e) = p^f \cdot p^{e-1} (p-1) = p^{e + f - 1} (p-1).$$
These are equal, which shows the claim.
